# cURL in PHP: curl_exec() or exec('curl')?

Tags: php, performance, bash, unix, curl

I've been wondering whether, despite of the obvious fact of granting access to the system shell, are there any performance flaws in using exec('curl') instead of curl_exec(), which demands a lot of pre-configuration and, thus, developing time, but is integrated with PHP, and what about threading and system resources?

Greetings :)

Comment: This is highly dependent on how you are using cURL.  What are you doing with the results?  You should just benchmark this for your individual situation.

Comment: You would still need to configure the command with string manipulation unless you are always using the same options... in my opinion using the curl extension is probably better unless you specifically want it to run in another process.

Comment: thank you very much. So curl_exec does not spawn a different process/thread to operate?

Answer (score 3):

It's totally different, `curl_exec()` is a function call, whereas `exec()` spawns another process.

Comment: i thought libcurl would also spawn another process to work, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it uses not `curl` command line utility, but `libcurl` library.

Comment: Ok, great, so it's doing something different - but what effect does that have? The question isn't asking if they are different - it is asking what *effect* that difference has. Are there any performance differences? Does it use a different amount of system resources? Processes or threads?

Comment: @Benubird, the difference is so dramatic, that I don't even know where to start. All in all, the effect is that process spawning is much more expensive than library call in terms of more or less all kinds of resources.